# Unable to convert string representation of dictionary to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file containing dictionaries like this:

```
{'name': 'peter', 'age': '16', 'class': None}
{'name': 'john', 'age': '20', 'class': 'B'}
{'name': 'alex', 'age': '18', 'class': 'C'}
```

I am trying to read the contents from the file and convert the lines back into dictionaries.

```
with open(file.txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'name' in line:
            d = json.loads(json.dumps(line.strip()))
            print(type(d))
```

But the type is still `str`? How can I get them to be dictionary object again?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not really, `line` is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: okay, sorry, then closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not JSON, but Python dictionary literals.

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast#ast.literal_eval) to convert literals to python object.

```
import ast

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'name' in line:
            d = ast.literal_eval(line)
            print(type(d))
```

Comment: But this is python 2

Comment: @rhillhouse, `ast.literal_eval` is available both in Python 2.x and Python 3.x. updated the link.

Comment: @rhillhouse The duplicate question says that ast.literal_eval is from Python 2.6

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, You're right. I left the `json.loads` by mistake. Thank you for your pointing.

Comment: Thank, this worked. I checked out the duplicate question, but as mentioned, it said it was for Python 2.6. Your answer worked perfectly.